# Calling a C++ function from OpenModelica

Tags: c++, openmodelica

I'm trying to call a function written in **C++** from OpenModelica.
Until now, I only found the calling of C function and wonder if Openmodelica supports C++ function.

Thanks for your responses

Comment: You can call the C++ function from the C function. The function called by Modelica needs to be C, so do: extern "C" { C function definition calling C++ }